# Angular: add HTML markup to string depending on keyboard input

Tags: html, angularjs, input, keyboard

I have an inputfield and I would like to print the input to the screen while I'm filling in the inputfield. However I'd like to scan the input text, to print certain words bold.

So for example, if I'm typing: "*Hello how are you?*"

I want it to be printed under the input field but *Hello* has to be in bold:
***Hello*** how are you ?

Is there a way in Angular to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you have to replace the words that you want to bold with `<b>Word</b>`,
you do that in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('textInput', function(){
  $scope.formattedText = $scope.textInput.replace(/(Hello|SomeWord|OtherWord)/ig, "<b>$1</b>");
});
```

And in the template

```
<div ng-bind-html="formattedText"></div>
```

*I used Regex to replace the words, `$1` is the matched word

*`ng-bind-html` directive to render as HTML and not as a **plain text**, it's kind of security by AngularJS, it don't let you put HTML directly in the `{{ formattedText }}`

Comment: Thank you, this works ! I was wondering if there was a way to make the make the Regex work for a variable? I have a variable list of strings to check. I'm guessing this isn't possible with Regex, but you never know

Comment: You can convert your array to a string:

``var regex = '('+words.join('|')+')';``
then use the RegExp Javascript class:
``regexObject = new RegExp(regex, 'ig');`` and then use it in the ``.replace(regexObject, ....)`` function
*I didn't tested the code tho

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can achieve it by using `NgModelController` (create a directive and use `require` property to get access to this controller).

[Here is a nice example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example) which intercepts the input and change it just before it is rendered, by implementing `$render` method on the required controller.

Another example that renders an input text into a bold one: http://jsbin.com/moxosorola/1/edit

Note that it does not change the value of the `ngModel` itself, but render it (the same `ngModel`) in the way you want to display it by using the custom directive (`bold-render`).